# Can you install more than one version of Android OS on to a single device?

Tags: android

I'm looking at doing some user testing on Android and need to test different versions of it going back to version 4.0.0.

If I got an Android device, could I install more than one OS on to it?

Comment: No. Use emulators. As an alternative, buy inexpensive used devices.

Comment: Searching Google for "dual-booting Android ROMs" seems to turn up some relevant results.

Answer (score 0):

If your device is Moto, you can use [Boot Menu Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.projectlense.bootmenu.manager)
.

Answer (score 0):

Never thought of searching for the term 'multi ROM'.  Found this interesting app, but only works on a select number of devices:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ykP354O711Q

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this. Not without a hack way.

To test in multiple devices and OS versions, you can use the Android Emulator included in the Android SDK.

You will have lots of problems with the emulator. The way it comes, it is really slow. Use this guide to make it more faster.

https://www.infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/articles/is-your-android-emulator-just-too-slow

Comment: Actually, there _do_ seem to be some dual-boot managers for some devices.

Answer (score -1):

Use an emulator instead.

I suggest https://www.genymotion.com/#!/ - It's far more responsive than the standard SDK emulator.

Answer (score -1):

**No** @David, Single device with Multiple versions of OS is not possible.

You can use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/) which is a fast and easy-to-use Android emulator to run and test your Android apps. It has [free version](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/pricing) also with some limited features.